# chrome pdf adjust to width by default

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, pdf-viewer

Is there any way I can tell Chrome to adjust the pdf width to the page width by default when opening? This would be so helpful (e.g. for overleaf, when I reload generated latex pdf over and over).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible depending on view method to fit chromes view either one of 2 ways

Using a Fragment on the viewer invocation

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-for-journals-template-with-bibtex-example-files-included/hjbyjvncdmpx.pdf#view=fith
[image]
[image]

### OR

When **inside a view its 2 keys** next to each other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>\</kbd>, which in Chrome is often a toggle between Height and Width

There also a setting in Edge that can help ensure on repeated call of same file the zoom is maintained,
[image]

**however its not in my default Chrome settings**.

[image]
[image]